# How to printout all matches facts in a rule

Tags: clips

I have a rule like below and I want to print all facts(here objct) that are compatible to this rule. I have a fact objct and there are some of these "objct"s that follow the rule. how I can do it? The printout below just prints the latest objct that player got. However I want to printout all of them. Any idea?

```
(defrule have_objcts   
?input <- (input have|possession)
   (objct (name ?n) (location player) (used 0))
   =>          
 ;WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE TO PRINTOUT those OBJCT's BELONG TO 
PALYER???????????
 (printout t crlf ?n)
   (retract ?input))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the matches command:

```
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate objct
   (slot name)
   (slot location)
   (slot used))
CLIPS>    
(deffacts initial
   (objct (name x) (location player) (used 0))
   (objct (name y) (location elsewhere) (used 1))
   (objct (name z) (location player) (used 0))
   (input have)
   (input want)
   (input possession)
   (input thing))
CLIPS>    
(defrule have_objcts   
   ?input <- (input have|possession)
   (objct (name ?n) (location player) (used 0))
   =>       
   (retract ?input)) 
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (matches have_objcts)
Matches for Pattern 1
f-4
f-6
Matches for Pattern 2
f-1
f-3
Partial matches for CEs 1 - 2
f-6,f-3
f-6,f-1
f-4,f-3
f-4,f-1
Activations
f-6,f-3
f-6,f-1
f-4,f-3
f-4,f-1
(4 4 4)
CLIPS> (run)
CLIPS> (matches have_objcts)
Matches for Pattern 1
 None
Matches for Pattern 2
f-1
f-3
Partial matches for CEs 1 - 2
 None
Activations
 None
(2 0 0)
CLIPS>
```

Comment: Thank you. However I want to printout all objct's in the have_objct rule. I mean There is a program and have_objct is just one rule that fires sometimes based on the mentioned rules. when it fires it should printout all the objct's that player has(location of the objct is player)

Comment: (printout t "location of the object is player" crlf)

Comment: Basic Programming Guide, http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/documentation/v630/bpg.pdf, section 12.4.2.3

Comment: Thank you Gary. I do not mean printing a message. I know how to printout a fact and a multifield fact. However I do not know how to print all facts(here objct's that belong to the player). In your solution x and z belong to player. Now how to print x and z before retracting the ?input. I edited the place I need to place the command.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: As I mentioned I want to printout the x and z that belongs to player and fires the have_objcts rule. I want to write some printout function to print x and z like this.

Comment: Dear Gary I changed the code again. Suppose I want to printout x and z.

Comment: I still have no idea what you're trying to do. Perhaps if you included sample data and the output you're expecting it might be clear.

Comment: CLIPS> (set-strategy lex)
lex
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (run)

***************************



*** What next?  south

You now can have a map. just pick it up.

*** What next?  get

You got the map now.!!!


*** What next?  have

You have map

*** What next?  north

Now your are at Skelly
Welcome to wonderland!


*** What next?  west

Now your are at Cafetaria
Go Blue


*** What next?  get pizza

You got the pizza now.!!!


*** What next?  have

You have pizza

*** What next?  have

You have pizza

*** What next?  eat pizza

You ate a pizza


*** What next?  have

You have map

*** What next?

Comment: Above is the running of my program right now. Look when the player gets the map and pizza it has both of them. then when it types have it should print both you have map and you have pizza. but as you see it just print the most recent fact. my strategy is lex(and should be)